# How do I set multiple notifications using one date selection?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-fragments, notifications

I need to set multiple notifications at the same time based on a list of mutiple choice questions. I will figure the radio buttons and if statements out later, for now I'm just setting the dates randomly for testing purposes.

If the user selects jan 1st and clicks a button.  It will set a notification in the future with a reminder to do an activity.  It also saves this information so the user can edit the details if he desires or change a few options.

This part I already have coded and it works just fine. however, It only sets a single notification currently.  It is a pretty involved code consisting database, receivers, fragments, etc. that all talk to each other.

As I said, this part I have working just fine but I am not including all the code because it is seriously involved and no one would try to break it down if i drown you in a sea of code. I can certainly post specific code if someone request it.

My issue is that I need it to set a good amount of notifications at various future dates upon the button click, not just one.  I need to change the notification message to a preset variable string for each additional notification event but some things like title will remain the same.

my current working code executes like this....

*User Selects Jan 1 > User Clicks Button > Notification set for Feb 14 with a unique title and message set by the user and saved for future editing...*

At the same time the notifications are set they are saved so the user can change the date and a few options if needed.  I want only one title and a single date saved.  I have the save feature already working but I need to know how to link the additional reminders to the existing saved item. Im trying to make all the data linked so that if the user deletes the saved item, all the set notifications for that file are deleted and not just the one that falls on the user selected date.

===== This is what I am trying to pull off

User Picks Some Options and Clicks A Button **[I have this working already]**

Upon Click of said button, the following notifications are all set in the future :

**[currently it sets this notification only]**
*Jan 1 notification* :
(title)Day Master App
(message)Happy New Year

**[Im trying to figure out how to add the following notifications upon the above button click and also save this information to the existing db under the same item]**

*Feb 14 notification* : (**title**)Day Master App - (**message**)Its V Day

*March 1 notification* : (**title**)Day Master App - (**message**)Spring Is Near

*March 14 notification* : (**title**)Day Master App - (**message**)Its probably raining

**(((and we'll just pretend i finished the list...)))**

I cant make the future notifications a static number because when the future notifications are set is determined by a bunch of radio button choices before the user clicks the execute button.  This is going to be a pretty complex and hacky if/else novel the way I think I have to do it.  Am I correct?

I have a display/edit listview that shows your saved notifications and the unique name and date the user set.  This works fine currently but only sets a single notification based on user input.

I need to add some more notifications but i dont need to save them under a different item or name.  I want them all under the same save item so all the notifications that were set when the button was clicked can be added and deleted as a group.  There will be no option to delete certain notifications that were set.  It will be all or none.

*I would imagine I could just add some more variables into the existing "save notification" code?  As in piggyback some more items (like all the dates and messages) for the additional notifications? do i need to write a new function for each future notification I set in order to be able to delete it? 
do I need to create a new db for each additional notification that is set? A separate Adapter? Im so confused...*

===

Im not looking for a code example exactly, I want to know how this would be implemented into an existing code.  I realize there is probably 100 ways to code what I have described.  I just need the process explained.

Please explain this to me slowly.  I know im way overthinking this.

I tried to explain this as best I could, if you need clarification on something please ask.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem although I could not accomplish exactly what I was trying to originally.

I managed to set the multiple notifications on a single click with different dates by simply copying the same code I used to display the single notification and simply giving each additional notification a unique ID and creating a new variables to give them individual text, future dates, separate times, etc. These variables can be easily set programmaticly or by the user when you set them up.

```
// On clicking the set notifications button
public void SetNotificationsButton(View v){
    ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(this);
// Creating Original Reminder
    int ID = rb.addReminder(new Reminder(mTitle, 
    mDate, mTime, mRepeat, mRepeatNo, mRepeatType, mActive));
// Create Feeding Notification
    int FeedingID = rb.addReminder(new Reminder("Have you fed the cat today?",
    mFeedingDate, mFeedingTime, mRepeat,  mRepeatNo, mRepeatType, mActive));
}
//
//   and just continued copy and pasting the rest of the notification events
//   changing the ID for each individual notification.  Without a unique ID  
//   the current notification will override the previous notification and
//   appear to only set the last reminder.
```

I was not able to remove all notifications by selecting a single list item, I probably could have figured this out by grouping the notifications into a separate variable but once I realized that you can only have a maximum of 50 notifications set at any given time it seemed like overkill.

Since I have a repeat option for certain notifications I can keep my notifications set; numbers low and stay away from the 50 at a time limit while still firing a reminder to the user every day.

I found a great example for setting single notifications I used as reference.
https://github.com/blanyal/Remindly

Thank those of you who took the time to read my question.